# dynamically construct instances python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Builder:

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):

        self.name = kwargs.pop("name", None)
        self.class_to_build = kwargs.pop("class", None)
        self.class_kwarguments = kwargs
        self.class_arguments = args

    def create_new_class(self):

        temp = self.class_to_build(*self.class_arguments,**self.class_kwarguments)
        return {self.name : temp}
```

So my question is how would I build python code to dynamically make an instance of an unspecified class. Above is my scratch code which I am sure is not how one goes about something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the * and ** notations infront of args and kwargs.

Say your class is C and you have a list args and a dict kw:

```
instnace = C(*args, **kwargs)
```

In your scenario you would need:

```
    temp = self.class_to_build(*self.class_arguments, **self.class_kwarguments)
```

Comment: Fixed but it wouldn't just run like that would it?

Comment: it should run, did you have problems running it?

Comment: Nope I was just surprised that was all